# post data using Http in angular 5 not working

Tags: angular

**news.service.ts**

I post data using http post but in the backend received an empty array

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

addNewsItem(data) {
  var url = this.url+"/addNews";
  return this.http.post(url,data)
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass :

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
```

as third parameter of `this.http.post()`

like : `this.http.post(url,data,httpOptions)(url,data,httpOptions)`

Answer (score 0):

Observables in Angular are "lazy" and won't be firing until you subscribe.

When you call addNewsItem, try this:

```
this.newsService.addNewsData(item).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```